# How to properly set up a Rust environment in VSCode on Debian?

Tags: debian, rust, visual-studio-code

I tried to set up VSCode to develop in Rust in Debian. My Rust installation is from the Debian repository, installed with

```
# aptitude install rustc
```

I installed the VSCode plugin `Rustycode` for the autocompletion but then came the problems: `racer` needs the Rust sources:

```
$ racer complete std::
RUST_SRC_PATH environment variable must be set to point to the src directory of a
rust checkout. E.g. "/home/foouser/src/rust/src"
```

I could not find the way to install the sources from the Debian repository, and I think this is the best practice because if `rustc` comes from the Debian repository and the sources from github, there could be some differences (different versions) between them.

I read something about `rustup`, I do not really understand its purpose, but I think it is like a package manager for Rust. I do not like this idea because a big advantage of Debian is the centralized package manager to update everything with one command.

Comment: *a big advantage of Debian is the centralized package manager to update everything with one command* — only if that centralized package manager has everything you need ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is ongoing work to make Rust be a first class installable citizen on Debian systems, but as far as I know, we are not there yet. For the time being, I would recommend apt-get uninstalling rustc, followed by:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

as suggested by [the Rust installation guides](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html).

I hate that approach to installation as much as the next guy, and recommend that you look at that shell script without blindly installing it, but ultimately you are trusting that upstream is doing the right thing.

In this case, at least, neither that shell script nor rustup require root access, so the default is just to install it all into `~/.rustup/`.

While I look forward to using apt to install Rust in the future on my own Debian laptop, I think doing anything other than the above will be swimming too much against the current recommended approach.

It's also worth nothing that the shell script installs `rustup`. `rustup` installs the main components, including `rustc` and `cargo`. What might not be obvious is that cargo can then install additional tools written in Rust, including racer:

```
cargo install racer
cargo install rustfmt
cargo install clippy
```

to name a few.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It's a shame that `rust-src` is not in the Debian repository.